# Unix command deleted every directory even though not specified

Tags: linux, bash, unix, xargs, rm

I am very new to the unix. I ran the following command.

```
ls -l | xargs rm -rf bark.*
```

and above command removed every directory in the folder.

Can any one explained me why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ls -l` command gave a list of all the subdirectories in your current present-working-directory (PWD).

The `rm` command can delete multiple files/directories if you pass them to it as a list.

eg: `rm test1.txt test2.txt myApp` will delete all three of the files with names:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
myApp
```

Also, the flags for the `rm` command you used are common in many a folly.
`rm -f` - Force deletion of files without asking or confirming
`rm -r` - Recurse into all subdirectories and delete all their contents and subdirectories

So, let's say you are in /home/user, and the directory structure looks like so:

```
 /home/user
|->dir1
|->dir2
`->file1.txt
```

the `ls -l` command will provide the list containing `"dir1 dir2 file1.txt"`, and the result of the command `ls -l | xargs rm -rf` will look like this:
`rm -rf dir1 dir2 file1.txt`

If we expand your original question with the example above, the final command that gets passed to the system becomes:
`rm -rf di1 dir2 file1.txt bark.*`

So, everything in the current directory gets wiped out, so the `bark.*` is redundant (you effectively told the machine to destroy everything in the current directory anyway).

I think what you meant to do was delete all files in the current directory and all subdirectories (recurse) that start with `bark.` To do that, you just have to do:
`find -iname bark.* | xargs rm`

The command above means "find all files in this directory and subdirectories, ignoring UPPERCASE/lowercase/mIxEdCaSe, that start with the characters "bark.", and delete them". This could still be a bad command if you have a typo, so to be sure, you should always test before you do a batch-deletion like this.

In the future, first do the following to get a list of all the files you will be deleting first to confirm they are the ones you want deleted.
`find -iname bark.* | xargs echo`

Then if you are sure, delete them via
`find -iname bark.* | xargs rm`

Hope this helps.

As a humorous note, one of the most famous instances of "rm -rf" can be found here:
https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/commit/a047be85247755cdbe0acce6f1dafc8beb84f2ac

An automated script runs something like `rm -rf /usr/local/.........`, but due to accidentally inserting a space, the command became `rm -rf /usr /local/......`, so this effectively means "delete all root folders that start with usr or local", effectively destroying the system of anyone who uses it. I feel bad for that developer.

You can avoid these kinds of bugs by quoting your strings, ie:
`rm -rf "/usr/ local/...."` would have provided an error message and avoided this bug, because the quotes mean that everything between them is the full path, NOT a list of separate paths/files (ie: you are telling rm that the file/folder has a SPACE character in its name).

Answer (score 10):

The `-r` argument means "delete recursively" (ie descend into subdirectories). The `-f` command means "force" (in other words, don't ask for confirmation). `-rf` means "descend recursively into subdirectories without asking for confirmation"

`ls -l` lists all files in the directory. `xargs` takes the input from `ls -l` and appends it to the command you pass to `xargs`

The final command that got executed looked like this:

```
rm -rf bark.* <output of ls -l>
```

This essentially removed `bark.*` **and** all files in the current directory. Moral of the story: be very careful with `rm -rf`. (You can use `rm -ri` to ask before deleting files instead)

Answer (score 6):

`rm(1)` deleted every file and directory in the current working directory because you asked it to.

To see roughly what happened, run this:

```
cd /etc ;  ls -l | xargs echo
```

Pay careful attention to the output.

I strongly recommend using `echo` in place of `rm -rf` when constructing command lines. Only if the output looks fine should you then re-run the command with `rm -rf`. When in doubt, maybe just use `rm -r` so that you do not accidentally blow away too much. `rm -ir` if you are *very* skeptical of your command line. (I have been using Linux since 1994 and I *still* use this `echo` trick when constructing slightly complicated command lines to selectively delete a pile of files.)

Incidentally, I would avoid parsing `ls(1)` output in any fashion -- filenames can contain *any* character except ASCII `NUL` and `/` chars -- including newlines, tabs, and output that *looks* like `ls -l` output. Trying to *parse* this with tools such as `xargs(1)` can be dangerous.

Instead, use `find(1)` for these sorts of things. To delete all files in all directories named `bark.*`, I'd run a command like this:

```
find . -type d -name 'bark.*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

Again, I'd use `echo` in place of `rm -r` for the first execution -- and if it looked fine, then I'd re-run with `rm -r`.

Comment: Now and then I find myself on systems without `find -print0` and the paired `xargs -0`.  Very very annoying. I think Solaris may be one such crippled cretin.